# Can Zxing be made to show camera feed in UIView

Tags: ios, window, zxing

I'm using the Objective-C port of Zxing called ZXingObjc without changing any of the code in the example project. I've wired up the IBOutlet UIView, scanRectView, and was expecting to see the camera feed in that rectangle. However, the whole screen is being used.

Seen lots of questions about getting Zxing to work but that's not my problem. Got it working just fine. I just don't want it taking over the whole screen. This is a native app, not in Xamarin or PhoneGap, etc.

I've tried modifying various CGRects (frames, etc.) in various places but nothing has worked so far. I believe it uses a rect of 1000 x 1000 like before a subViews are played out so I've attempted to code around that. Still not working.

Anyone got this working in a particular rectangle on iOS?

Comment: FWIW you can do this with Core Image and bypass Zxing

Comment: What about the bar code reading?

Comment: Yes, Core Image can detect barcodes directly. Sorry.  I meant to include the link with my previous comment.  http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2013/10/10/scanning-barcodes-with-ios-7-objective-c.aspx

Comment: Holy API, Batman! I totally missed that addition to iOS 7. Thanks, I'll try that!